# WordPress Network admin options page: how to store options and where will they be stored?

Tags: multisite, options, network-admin

I'm creating an additional WordPress Network admin page, and I need to store some system-wide option.
The good thing that a config file will  be generated, so no access is required from the child blogs, but the question is: how to store options to Network Admin, and where will they be stored in the database?

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`add_site_option()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/add_site_option) and `update_site_option()`. You can find these functions in `wp-includes/functions.php`.

Comment: And as far as I see those will be stored in the sitemeta table if network is enabled and will fall back to options table if not.